# Default selector for selected View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-selector

I think the question says it all: Is there a default Selector from `@android/drawable` which I can set as background for my view if I call:

```
view.setSelected(true);
```

I want to use the default colors from android but in a custom Selector I can only add own drawables. Is there a default selector for this? Or can I access the default drawables for that so I can use them in my own Selector?

I tried with `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` but If I call `view.setSelected(true);` nothing happened.

Comment: In the above drawable(android:attr/selectableItemBackground) there is no drawable specified for the state **android:state_selected**.

Comment: Okay but what other default resource xan I use for this?

Comment: Actually what is your requirement ? what you meant by default drawables ?

Comment: Hey. Im using the default too. How did you solve this? Which state do you finally use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
      android:state_selected="true"> <!-- selected -->
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid
          android:color="#444444"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item> <!-- not selected -->
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid
          android:color="#888888"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: But I really want to use a default selector from Android.

Answer (score 0):

In the above drawable(android:attr/selectableItemBackground) there is no drawable specified for the state **android:state_selected**.